# Автоматическое обновление представления

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Необходимо написать скрипт который автоматически добавить в представление столбец. Как вообще обычно решается данная задача? Представление сложное и просто добавить стоблец в конец не могу. replace() не работает, полагаю из-за непечатаемых символов.

Скрипт представления получаю так:

```
SELECT 
@SQL_Command = sc.text 
FROM sys.objects o
join sys.syscomments sc on o.object_id = sc.id
WHERE o.name = 'MyView'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел способ обойти все проблемы:

```
-- создаем временную табличку
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_Script') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP_Script
GO
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_Script (codeline nvarchar(250))

-- кладем в нее скрипт представления
INSERT #TEMP_Script
EXEC sp_helptext 'MyView'

--!--
--На данном этапе вы можете заменить CREATE на ALTER, если того требует ваша
--реализация + произвести все необходимые изменения в скрипте представления

--обьявляем переменную для выполнения модифицированного скрипта
DECLARE @SQL_Command nvarchar(max)

--Кладем в нее скрипт
SELECT @SQL_Command = (SELECT codeline + '' FROM #TEMP_Script FOR XML PATH(''))

--Выполняем 
exec sp_executesql @SQL_Command
```

Подробнее о:
[sp_executesql](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) и [sp_helptext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Надеюсь это пригодится кому-то кроме меня)